# Remove row from table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I try to delete the row on click last 'td' contain class '.del' in each row except second row.
Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yWwvp) for demo of the code

Please help me to correct the code

```
jQuery(".del").click(function () {
    jQuery(this).closest("tr:not(':first')").remove();
    //jQuery(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
jQuery(".del").click(function() {
     jQuery(this).closest("tr:not(':first-child')").remove();
});
```

`jQuery(this).closest("tr:not(':first')")` - this is effectively "select closest `tr`, which is exactly 1 element, then remove `:first` element from the set, i.e. leave none".

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery("tr:not(:first-child) .del").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest("tr").remove();
    //jQuery(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery(".del").click(function() {
  $tr = jQuery(this).closest("tr");
  if(!$tr.is(':first-child')) {
   $tr.remove();
  }
 });
```

Comment: jQuery(this).closest("tr:not(':first-child')").remove();

Use first-child instead of first